Manual SVD Implementation in Python failed
I am trying to implement a function for Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) in Python by myself, using the eigenvalue decomposition of A^T A and AA^T, but the reconstructed matrix (B) does not always match the original matrix (A). Here is my code:
import numpy as np
# Generate a random matrix A
row, col = 3, 3
A = np.random.normal(size=row * col).reshape(row, col)

# Eigen decomposition of A^T*A and A*A^T
ATA = A.T @ A
AAT = A @ A.T
eigenvalues_ATA, eigenvectors_ATA = np.linalg.eig(ATA)
eigenvalues_AAT, eigenvectors_AAT = np.linalg.eig(AAT)

# Sort eigenvalues and eigenvectors
idx_ATA = eigenvalues_ATA.argsort()[::-1]
idx_AAT = eigenvalues_AAT.argsort()[::-1]
sorted_eigenvectors_ATA = eigenvectors_ATA[:, idx_ATA]
sorted_eigenvectors_AAT = eigenvectors_AAT[:, idx_AAT]

# Calculate singular values
sorted_singularvalues_ATA = np.sqrt(np.abs(eigenvalues_ATA[idx_ATA]))
sorted_singularvalues_AAT = np.sqrt(np.abs(eigenvalues_AAT[idx_AAT]))

# Construct diagonal matrix S
S = np.zeros_like(A)
np.fill_diagonal(S, sorted_singularvalues_ATA)

# Reconstruct matrix B
B = sorted_eigenvectors_AAT @ S @ sorted_eigenvectors_ATA.T
print(np.allclose(A, B))

Could anyone know why this reconstruction only occasionally match the original matrix A?
# Example it works
A_equal = [-1.59038869, -0.28431377,  0.36309318,
           0.07133563, -0.20420962,  1.82207923,
           0.84681193,  0.31419994, -0.93808105]

# Example it fails
A_not_equal = [ 1.61171729,  0.6436384,   0.47359656,
               -1.04121454,  0.17558459,  0.36595138,
                0.40957221,  0.20499528,  0.18525562]
A = np.array(A_not_equal).reshape(3,3)

# Expected output
[[ 1.61171729  0.6436384   0.47359656]
 [-1.04121454  0.17558459  0.36595138]
 [ 0.40957221  0.20499528  0.18525562]]

# Actual output
[[-1.61240387 -0.63872607 -0.47789066]
 [ 1.04102391 -0.17422069 -0.36714363]
 [-0.40734839 -0.22090623 -0.17134711]]
 


What is an example of a matrix where it fails? What output did you expect, and what output did you get? Working through the algorithm step by step, what is the first step that fails?

Thank you. When it fails, it seems like the signs are reversed and the numbers are slightly off after the decimal point.

Thank you. Finally I found that I have to compute V first and then compute U from A and V. Computing V from ATA and U from AAT separately does not always work.

please Answer your own Question rather than vandalizing it with updated code!

I've started the re-open request, given you really do have an Answer! (and imo quite suitable for SO)

Oh, waw, I study physical oceanography and we said it EOF (Empirical Orthogonal Function). If I remember it correctly (sine I had same problems once), your code has not considered eigenvalue degeneracy and sign indeterminacy. Please google them and I hope you'll be able to solve it.

Thanks to @Ghorban M. Tavakoly, now I understand it's due to sign indeterminacy. To avoid it, I need to reconstruct U (or Vt) first from ATA (or AAT) and then the other one using the reconstructed U (or Vt). Here is the updated code:
import numpy as np
# Generate a random matrix A
row,col = 5,3
A = np.random.normal(size=row * col).reshape(row,col)

# Eigen decomposition of A^T*A
ATA = A.T @ A
eigenvalues_ATA,eigenvectors_ATA = np.linalg.eig(ATA)

# Sort eigenvaluess and eigenvectors
idx_ATA = eigenvalues_ATA.argsort()[::-1]
sorted_eigenvectors_ATA = eigenvectors_ATA[:,idx_ATA]
sorted_eigenvalues_ATA = eigenvalues_ATA[idx_ATA]

# Calculate singular values
sorted_singularvalues_ATA = np.sqrt(np.abs(sorted_eigenvalues_ATA))

# Construct diagonal matrix S and (1/S)^T
S = np.zeros_like(A)
np.fill_diagonal(S, sorted_singularvalues_ATA[:len(S)])
S_inverse_transpose = np.zeros_like(A).T
np.fill_diagonal(S_inverse_transpose, 1/sorted_singularvalues_ATA[:len(S)])

# Reconstruct U and then the original matrix as B
U = A @ sorted_eigenvectors_ATA.T @ S_inverse_transpose
B = U @ S @ sorted_eigenvectors_ATA
print(np.allclose(A,B))

